# Kill all user sessions using dynamic SQL - exec within exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, exec

> Environment: SQL Server 2005/2008

I would like to kill all the user connections on a particular DB using dynamic SQL. I am aware of other methods like altering the DB mode to single/offline etc., but would like to do using dynamic SQL.

I am trying to avoid cursor, while loop and also any usage of variable in executing the dynamic SQL. Here is my code using sysprocesses:

```
 
-- Construct KILL SQL
exec ('select ''kill '' + cast(spid as varchar(20)) + '';'' from sys.sysprocesses
    where spid NOT IN (@@spid)
    and spid > 50')
```

After constructing individual kill statements now I would like to exec without declaring and using a variable as below. Am I missing something or that an exec within exec doesn't work?

```
  
-- execute KILL SQL
exec ('exec (''select ''''kill '''' + cast(spid as varchar(20)) + '''';'''' from sys.sysprocesses
where spid NOT IN (@@spid)
and spid > 50'')')
```

I know a better way to declare a variable and do it as below but I would like above to work if it is possible without using a variable:

```
 
-- routine way of doing KILL
declare @dsql nvarchar(max)=''
select @dsql = 'kill ' + cast(spid as varchar(20)) + ';' from sys.sysprocesses
where spid NOT IN (@@spid)
and spid > 50
exec(@dsql)
```

Comment: Why so many constraints, like no variables?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the much simpler solution: ALTER DATABASE db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;?

Comment: @Aaron..my original question was - why was I not allowed to perform an exec within exec? above example was just a minor implementation of that idea...I totally agree I would go with any of the other simple soultions for this problem...can you please let me know why the second query doesnt work?

Comment: @Aaron..contd from above..I would like to extend this idea to any stored procedure not introducing any temp. table or table variables while dynamically constructing SQL string and doing the exec of dynamic SQL in one shot rather than inserting once into temp table and then again looping thru records to execute the sql..

Answer (score 1):

None of your solutions is restricted to only one database. your code kill all user sessions in all databases.

```
declare @dsql nvarchar(max)=''
select @dsql = 'kill ' + cast(spid as varchar(20)) + ';' from sys.sysprocesses
where spid NOT IN (@@spid)
and spid > 50
AND dbid = <your database id>
exec(@dsql)
```

But the Problem with all these kill options per code will be the same:
Set a database offline without the AdminSession will not kill reliable all sessions. And i also have no solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that your last version is the best solution.