# Incorrect syntax near '(' with KILL query using SELECT subquery

Tags: sql-server

I can't use KILL function with SELECT subquery.

```sql
KILL (SELECT spid FROM master..sysprocesses WHERE hostprocess = '6672')
```

I receive this error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '('. Expecting '-', ID, INTEGER, NUMERIC, STRING, or TEXT_LEX.

I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: That's a very product specific syntax. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I found solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637992/kill-all-user-sessions-using-dynamic-sql-exec-within-exec